# ValueError in tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to run a program which uses tensorflow agents & tensorflow probability at the back end. When I try to run the train.py using .yaml input file, I am getting the following error:

lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/internal/prefer_static.py", line 84, in _copy_docstring
raise ValueError(

ValueError: Arg specs do not match: original=FullArgSpec(args=['input', 'dtype', 'name', 'layout'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None, None, None), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={}), new=FullArgSpec(args=['input', 'dtype', 'name'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None, None), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={}), fn=<function ones_like_v2 at 0x7f8287141480>
Please help me understand the issue & any suggestions to resolve the error is greatly appreciated.

For reference prefer_static.py has the following code related to ones_like:

def *ones_like(input, dtype=None, name=None):  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
s = *shape(input)
s* = tf.get_static_value(s)
if s* is not None:
return np.ones(s_, dtype_util.as_numpy_dtype(dtype or input.dtype))
return tf.ones(s, dtype or input.dtype, name)
ones_like = _copy_docstring(tf.ones_like, _ones_like)

Comment: Probably version skew. Can you post `pip list | grep "tf\|tfp\|tensorflow"`?